# Evaluation of Derivative Using $\epsilon−\delta$ Definition

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, continuity, characteristic-functions

Consider the function $f \colon\mathbb R \to\mathbb R$ defined by
$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
  x^2\sin(1/x); & \text{if }x\ne 0, \\
  0 & \text{if }x=0.
\end{cases}$

Use $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition to prove that the limit $f'(0)=0$.

Now I see that h should equals to delta; and delta should equal to epsilon in this case. Thanks for everyone contributed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the definition of a derivative i.e. $$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+h) - f(x)}h$$
Hence, we get that
$$f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{2h^2 \sin(1/h)-0}h = \lim_{h \to 0} 2h \sin(1/h)$$
Now recall that $\vert \sin(y) \vert \leq 1$. Hence, we have that
$$\left \vert 2h \sin(1/h) \right \vert \leq \left \vert 2h \right \vert$$
Hence, we have that $$\lim_{h \to 0} \left \vert 2h \sin(1/h) \right \vert \leq \lim_{h \to 0} \left \vert 2h \right \vert = 0$$
Hence, you get that
$$f'(0) = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\left|{\dfrac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}}\right|=\left|{\dfrac{2h^2 \sin{\dfrac{1}{h}}}{h}}\right|=2 \left|{h \sin{\dfrac{1}{h}}}\right|<2\left|h\right|<\varepsilon.$$
Choose $\delta<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}.$